# How comes that we use space and time together in one manifold?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime

I know and understand that the speed of light is constant in vacuum. It's been the experiment of Michelson amd Morley that took us to this finding.

I know and understand Einsteins special and general relativity.

I only miss one step: How did Einstein (or mankind, or physicists) come to the conclusion that it's a 4D spacetime?
Instead of just leaving space as ist is and time as it is and just postulate the maximal velocity?

It's that difficult now to chose an appropriate coordinate system.

Furthermore, time *is* different to space: it's not possible to travel in it, and it only runs forward.

Comment: It seems obvious to me that Lorentz transformations mix time and space and so in order to have a single object on which they act you have to "invent" spacetime. Do you disagree, or is this meant to be a *historical* question (and should be tagged with [tag:history] or at [hsm.SE])?

Comment: The idea of a 4-dimensional object describing space and time is not at all a new feature of SR/GR. This is also prevalent in classical mechanics. In classical mechanics, the thing everyone agrees with is “what is time”, i.e within our 4D spacetime we have a time function, whose level sets are a bunch of 3-dimensional spaces $\Bbb{R}^3$ stacked on top of one another (the hypersurfaces of simultaneity).  In SR, the thing we agree on is the speed of light, so phrased geometrically, the thing we agree on is the collection of 3D cones (the light cones in the tangent spaces) in the 4D spacetime.

Comment: The Michelson Morley experiment was a marvelous achievement but it was not in fact this one which influenced Einstein to propose Special Relativity; he was guided by other experiments and by electromagnetic theory. The 4d geometric view of spacetime is associated with Minkowski.

Comment: @scibo There is already inherent symmetry in spacetime of classical kinematics equations,- $x=x_0+vt$ or $x=x_0+(-v)(-t)$. Like you can cover same displacement moving forwards in space and forwards in time or backwards in space and backwards in time (whether or not it's possible in practice is another story, albeit [quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mechanics_of_time_travel) says it could be possible in some way).

Comment: https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Space_and_Time_(Hermann_Minkowski)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime#Spacetime_interval

Comment: " How did Einstein (or mankind, or physicists) come to the conclusion" Do you literally mean to ask a historical question about Einstein's process, or do you mean "how can I understand this concept"

Comment: It is not possible to travel in space without travelling in time too, so the last point is moot.

Answer (score 2):

Start off with 3D vectors. If you have a vector in one set of coordinates, then rotate the coordinate axes, you end up with the same vector needing to be expressed in the new coordinate system. A linear transformation exists to transform the components from one coordinate system to those of another. Quantities which remain unchanged under a rotation of the coordinate axes are scalars, those whose coordinates transform like those of a position vector are vectors themselves.

In flat space, $-c^2dt^2+dx^2+dy^2+dz^2=-c^2d\tau^2$. This takes the form of a dot product or norm in 4 dimensions.  $(icdt, dx,dy,dz)\cdot (icdt, dx,dy,dz)=-c^2d\tau^2 $ This motivates considering the product $cdt$ which does have units of distance on equal footing with other components of position. There are other motivations.

Consider charge conservation: $\nabla\cdot \vec{J}+\partial \rho /\partial t=0$

Throw in $c$ whenever you see the time you get this $\nabla \cdot \vec{J} +(1/c)\partial (c\rho)/\partial  t=0$

In cartesian coordinates, this becomes $\partial J_x/\partial x+\partial J_y/\partial y + \partial J_z/\partial z+(1/c)(\partial/\partial t)(\rho c)=0$

This motivates expressing the divergence as$( \frac{1}{c} \partial/ \partial t, \partial/\partial x, \partial/ \partial y, \partial / \partial z) \cdot (\rho c, J_x, J_y, J_z)=0 $

It can be simplified as $ (\frac{1}{c} \partial/\partial t, \nabla) \cdot (\rho c, \vec{J})=0$

Consider the Lorentz Gauge: $\nabla \cdot \vec{A}+\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}=0$

$(\frac{1}{c} \partial/\partial t, \nabla) \cdot (V/c, \vec{A})=0$

Over and over again we are again we have relations between three space derivatives and a time derivative.

The frequent occurrence of time derivatives mixed with space derivatives and a implied way of using and norming four vectors motivates connected time and space into a single manifold.

Just as behavior under rotations determines what it means to be a vector in 3 dimensions, Lorentz Transforms dictate a similar rule for 4-vectors. In fact, 3D rotations are a subset of Lorentz Transforms.

The Rotation transform in 3D effectively mixes $x,y,z$ components from the original coordinate system into components in the new system $x',y'z'$.  For example $x'=ax+by+cz$ for some constant values of $a,b,c$. $x'$ is a mixture of $x,y,z$.

The Lorentz transform takes space and time coordinates from one coordinate system and mixes them together to get the coordinates in the new coordinate system.

The Lorentz Transform implies you can use a linear operator on a 4vector to get a new 4 vector. Other considerations imply you can do vector calculus using those 4 vectors so we use a 4D manifold.

We do travel in time into the future one second at a time in our own reference frame. In another frame we move relative to, we move some distance in space per a unit of their proper time and some "distance" in time vs. their proper time. The rate of time in one frame is different from the other giving rise to time dilation, traveling into the future at different rates.

Answer (score 2):

Let's suppose a 2D (1 + 1) non relativistic world, and a distance $d$ and time interval $t$ between 2 events in a given frame. Any space-time metric $f(t,d) \neq f(t)$ would not be invariant, because for another frame with suitable velocity, both events would be at the same location ($d=0$). On the other hand, for simultaneous events ($t=0$), a space-time metric $f(t,d) = f(d)$ could be used for any frame.

In SR, it is possible to choose $f(d,t) = t^2 - d^2$ as a suitable metric, due to its invariance to change of coordinates. While it is also possible to define a space-time for a Newtonian world, it doesn't have a (invariant) metric.

Answer (score 2):

Michaelson and Morley demonstrated that light has always the same speed in all frames of reference. The simplest answer to your question, then, is that if you are in a model with absolute time and absolute space (like in classical mechanics), then the speed of an object *always* depends on the frame of reference you choose. So it would not make sense to say that the speed of light is fixed as an absolute constant, as by changing the frame of reference you would change the speed of light (e.g., light would trivially have speed zero in its own frame of reference...).

The question then was: how do you make a theory in which light has the same speed in **all** frames of reference? The first answer was special relativity, in which Einstein basically said "you know what, I'll simply assume light has the same speed in all frames of reference, and from that I will deduce how reality looks like". And it turned out that using spacetime as in SR, with no absolute time or space, light has the same speed in all frames of reference. This is the basic idea of why you cannot have absolute time and absolute space.